# Unable to Install Extensions in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am trying to install any of the extensions in VSCode, it gives me the same error.

> "Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in
> namespace 'AnonymousId'. For more information on why your request was
> blocked, see the topic "Rate limits" on the Microsoft Web site
> (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950)."

I am unable to understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I have the same issue right now, looking at [a similar problem on the vscode forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/request-was-blocked-due-to-exceeding-usage-of-reso/724011) it seems that this is just a temporary outage that occurs every now and then with absolutely terrible error messages?